# Response.Redirect on button within modal

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

Why does `Response.Redirect(...)`not work when it is within the on_click method of a button within a modal? I am trying to have a "log in" button redirect to another page, but for some reason since this "log in" button is within a modal, there is no response of any sort. What is a proper method to approach this?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mdlLogIn" role="dialog">
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogInFinal" runat="server" Text="Log In" CssClass="btn btn-Orange" OnClick="btnLogInFinal_click" />
</div>
```

C# code:

```
    protected void btnLogInFinal_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/somepage.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: It is not clear where that Response.Redirect is and how you try to make it execute, so I am not sure how we can help you with such a limited information. Recommended reading - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Response.Redirect is within the on_click method of a button in the .cs file. This button is located inside of a modal.

Comment: please add a piece of code. Response.Redirect is a server-side method. Probably your button is not making the call back.

Comment: This is never an issue with buttons that are not inside of a modal. I will post the code in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your modal is outside the `<form></form>`. Rewrite your JS code to add modal inside `<form></form>`  and it will work.

Comment: I did not use any JS code for that. I used C# code.

Comment: Your modal is done with HTML CSS and JavaScript, not C#. Bootstrap modals make a copy of themselves and put it outside the form element. When you click the button, that button is no longer part of the form so all it does is postback. It isn't able to send the event target that would wire it up correctly to the button click event on the server. Having this be an asp.net button is just a waste of time. Change it to a regular button, or better yet, make it a link. It'll just work. <a href="somepage.aspx" class="btn btn-Orange">Log in</a>